# Is there an API to add UV data from a YUV 420p frame to CVPixelBufferRef without interleaving the U and V data

Tags: ios, swift

I have YUV 420p frames from a video streaming.  I use CVPixelBufferRef to render the video to GLKView.  After creating the CVPixelBufferRef and when putting the UV data into it, they have to be interleave.  For 2K plus frames, this really slow down the streaming.  I have these two questions.  Why does Apple interleave the Y & V data?  Is there an API or structure in CVPixelBufferRef that just take the UV data directly.